# Search in a ListView results in a null object reference

Tags: android, listview

I'm going through these API Guides: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html
and willing to implement searching in my simple ListView. I just don't know why i'm getting this:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void >android.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView$OnQuer>yTextListener)' on a null object reference

This is my code. Please help me to figure this out:

```
MenuItem ourSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) ourSearchItem.getActionView();

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please check if/ why `SearchView searchView` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `actionViewClass` attribute in your menu item XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:title="@string/search_title"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

or if you use support library:

```
 app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I did it the same way you posted. I just forgot to include it in the question. Still getting this error(

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check again? Replaced 'android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView' with 'app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView'

Comment: Perfect! It works! Thank you! Instead of app:actionViewClass I had android:actionViewClass, that was the mistake...